# SE Data Explorer always logs me out

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I am using Google Login for SEDE. After a day or so, I always find myself logged out, even though I did not delete my cookies etc.

I am using Safari 11.0 on macOS 10.13.

Is there a setting for staying logged in or did I miss something? Is it because my token expires?